# Docopt single dash arguments without spaces

Tags: python, docopt

I am using docopt to handle my command line program, but I am having some issues with the single dash ('-') switches. I would like to be able to take commands either like this:

```
    foo.py -a 1
```

or like this

```
    foo.py -a1
```

My program currently does the first, but it does not do the second. Here is what I currently have:

```
    Usage:
      foo.py [-a <address>]

    Options:
      -a            Set address
```

I've tried changing the usage to

```
    Usage:
      foo.py [-a<address]
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using `docopt`.

From the [documentation](http://docopt.org/):

> Short options can be "stacked", meaning that `-abc` is equivalent to `-a -b -c`.

Docopt wouldn't know if `-a1` was the parameter "1" for argument `a` or the stacked version
of `-a -1`.